# "No such file or directory" when moving a file in Linux when file exists

Tags: linux, unix, mv

Im trying to rename a file by removing the _proc* suffix:

```
[root@mbdprod05 ~]# ls -ltr /mediation/collection/h-sgsn/*.proc*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 x340271 soul 4191657 Feb  9 22:13 /mediation/collection/h-sgsn/20180209221331_CGW1CLI_AP71_b68737.dat.proc_6181
-rw-rw-r-- 1 x340271 soul 4131571 Feb  9 22:14 /mediation/collection/h-sgsn/20180209221331_CGW1CLI_AP67_b61519.dat.proc_7243
-rw-rw-r-- 1 x340271 soul 4161847 Feb  9 22:14 /mediation/collection/h-sgsn/20180209221331_CGW1MUN_AP71_b73442.dat.proc_5278
-rw-rw-r-- 1 x340271 soul 4220105 Feb  9 22:17 /mediation/collection/h-sgsn/20180209221331_CGW1CLI_AP70_b98531.dat.proc_8133
[root@mbdprod05 ~]# mv /mediation/collection/h-sgsn/20180209221331_CGW1CLI_AP67_b61519.dat.proc_7243 /mediation/collection/h-sgsn/20180209221331_CGW1CLI_AP67_b61519.dat
mv: cannot stat `/mediation/collection/h-sgsn/20180209221331_CGW1CLI_AP67_b61519.dat.proc_7243': No such file or directory
[root@mbdprod05 ~]#
```

As you can see, the file exists, but i cant do anyhing to it and i'm the administrator.

Comment: try surrounding both versions of the filename in dbl-quotes? Good luck.

Comment: Sorry, thats my bad by copy pasting. In the console it looks ok.

Comment: Have you tried using tab completion to match the filename?

Comment: Is it a temporary file that is removed by proces `7243` as soon as the processing is finished? The filename ends with `proc_7243`. Can you do a `ls` after the error message?

Comment: Those files are generated and moved all the time (they remain a few minutes there), but when i do ls on the file it still exists but i get that error.